# HTML tags, CSS and Javascript developer tool for Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari

Are there and tools for Safari like there are Developer Tools for IE8 and Firebug for Firefox?

Comment: Please do basic research before asking on StackOverflow: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=safari+developer+tools

Comment: Really, you thought I didnt do that.

Comment: Try Ctrl+Shift+J or Command+Option+J, too, for a great Developer Tools console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, enable it in the menus edit>preferences>advanced> show Develop menu in menu bar

Answer (score 2):

try https://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html